# CouchDB or Mongo for very high update rates & volume?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

What would be the best no-sql alternative for storing user data with very high update rates and volume of data?

e.g dumping tens to hundreds of lines of user state / navigation state data per page request for a high volume site.

I'm currently looking at Mongo or Couch but am open to other alternatives.

**EDIT** (in response to kprobst's request):
It would be hosted on Linux and multiple instances (either HW or VM) can be made available.

The system would used to store a site visitors state, 1-2 weeks for unauthenticated users and (potentially) indefinitely for authenticated users.

I think the current way of thinking within the business is to use CouchDB as we use it elsewhere, but I also keep reading it's the most under-performant for constant updating and there is the potential in this system to be updating 30 - 400 lines of json into multiple documents, per user, as a user interacts with the site (usage is expected to be very high).

Besides this state "dump" other user information would be stored and being able to querying that would be useful.

Comment: I prefer MongoDB for such kind of analytic work. You can use MongoDB's auto-sharding and improve the write-scaling. Its possible to write in parallel on each shard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently investigated into a number of NoSQL technologies including CouchDB and MongoDB. The feeling I got was that MongoDB is more geared towards performance than CouchDB, possibly at the expense of certain features. e.g. MongoDB uses language specific drivers, CouchDB uses REST. MongoDB is "Update In Place" whereas CouchDB is [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). MongoDB stores data in memory-mapped files.

I chose MongoDB because it suited the type of data I want to store and the performance it offers. IMHO, I don't think an MVCC solution would be the best fit for the use you've described. As a document is updated, instead of overwriting the existing document, it creates a new version of it and then marks the old one as obsolete meaning those ones need to periodically be deleted/compacted. The more updates there are, the more work this will involve which would be my concern.

This is not to say MongoDB is the "better" choice over CouchDB, as they offer different things and what may be a disadvantage of one technology in a specific scenario, could well be an advantage in another scenario. You obviously have the advantage with CouchDB of already using it within the business so presumably less of a learning curve.

There's a bit more of a comparison of the 2 on [MongoDB.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB).

Comment: Mongo achieved performance at the cost of ACID. So, if consistency is a required feature, CouchDB is more suitable.

Comment: IMHO, mongodb has higher consistency than CouchDB because mongodb uses master-slave replication and write is only on the master node. CouchDB uses async master-master replication and provide "eventual consistency".

Comment: CouchDB allows master to master but is not master to master unless you set it up to be as such.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what platform you're running on, or what platform you can host your nosql solution in. You also don't specify if you want a straight distributed key-value store, or a NoSQL database, which would be MongoDB. The two things are not the same, although a NoSQL database can be used as a kv store, I suppose.

That said, if you need a simple key-value store that runs well on Linux, I'd go with [Redis](http://redis.io/). Of all the NoSQL solutions I've only used MongoDB, but it runs well on Server 2008 (64 bit) and great on Linux (CentOS).

It really depends on what you need, and where you can host it. MongoDB for example pretty much requires at least two instances. If you provide more information maybe someone can give you a better recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Membase is a disk-persisted clustered memory-based NoSQL database. It was developed by several memcached leaders. In addition to its native protocol, it also has a 100% memcache-compatible API too. Membase is already used in very high-volume applications, such as Farmville.

Membase and CouchOne merged into Couchbase (where I work, FWIW, but I don't work on Membase). Therefore it seems reasonable that the future of Membase will have CouchDB features: map-reduce query, replication/backup off-site, HTTP REST interface, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo), which is often used to support large web-based applications and infrastructure (Amazon.com, for example). Berkeley DB supports both a key/value API (NoSQL) as well as a SQL API. If you're building a Java-based SOA solution, you may want to consider [BDB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/dM4Qtw) which is used by the [Heretix Way Back Machine](http://crawler.archive.org/).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Product Managers for Berkeley DB, so I am a little biased. That said, BDB was written to provide a fast, scalable, reliable embedded data store for exactly the kinds of operations that you describe.